# DNN - 500 Internal Server error

Tags: dotnetnuke

I recently inhereted a DNN site that has went down as of yesterday (I made no changes to it).

On the front end I see the error

> 500 - Internal server error.
>   There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

I looked at the logs in /Portals/_default/Logs and I see

> "2018-08-21 05:57:01,024 [WEBA9][Thread:37][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Common.Initialize - The connection to the database has failed, however, the application is already completely installed, a 500 error page will be shown to visitors"

Does anyone know how I could begin to start debugging this? I'm completely new to DNN. Thanks!

Comment: I'd check that the correct database connection is used in both "connectionsStrings" in your web.config

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to start by looking at your web.config file in the root of the site.

From there you'll find the connection string. (control-F to search)

Using the Connection information in that connection string, you should try

Try remoting into the database server to see if you can access it via Remote Desktop, can you access it? Does that server need rebooting?

Try connecting to the database using SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) using the username/pwd in the connection string.

I imagine that the SQL server is for some reason offline, and you'll need to get it back up and running.

Comment: Since I provided that on Reddit, I figured I would provide it here too :D

Answer (score 0):

It can happen after a reboot of the server. When IIS with the DNN site comes online earlier than the SQL server is done loading.

Stopping and starting the AppPool of the DNN installation might help.